# Adhearsion Park Asterisk call

Tags: asterisk, adhearsion

I'm using Asterisk 11.5.1 with Adhersion

Is there any way to put on hold or park an existing call on Adhearsion (known from its call_id) , in order to originate an other call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in a few ways. You could use adhearsion-asterisk and then directly execute the asterisk commands to park the call. Alternatively you can use in call apps such as Matrioska to provide additional in call functionality. Or you can unjoin the call and put it on hold by playing some hold music. Then originate the new call and join them as needed.

See: https://mojolingo.com/blog/2013/call-apps-attended-transfers for the in call app stuff